# deviceready in multipages and google analytics plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, google-analytics, phonegap-build

in my phonegap app I have the following architecture:

-index.html

-page1.html

-page2.html
...

I add this to the index.html in order to use the google analytics plugin (https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin/):

```
<script>       
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-1233455-1');
    window.analytics.trackView('Home');
}  
</script>
```

And this to the other pages (page1.html in this example):

```
<script>       
    window.analytics.trackView('page1');
</script>
```

In GA I only saw the 'Home' screen and don't see other screens.

Do I miss something or do this plugin don't work with multiple pages architecture?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin#javascript-usage), the `window.analytics.trackView('page1');` call has to be in the `deviceReady` section of the app. Since your `trackView` calls on separate pages aren't included there, they won't be called.

In your `deviceReady`, you should be able to call an if / else statement that would fire on each page.

Comment: But I understand that deviceReady only fire once on the first load of the app, is it true? So if yes it may be difficult to build an else/if statement to detect the right page?

Comment: Yes, if you load cordova.js on multiple pages, you should be able to set it up that way.

Comment: So if I understand I must add cordova.js on each page and add `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` and my onDeviceReady function on each page too, is that right?

Comment: Yes. It should work. If not, it's most likely an error somewhere else in your code.

Comment: You've got it! I call the cordova.js in my /page1.html like that `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>` but I must call like that : `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../cordova.js"></script>` ....

Answer (score 0):

> But I understand that deviceReady only fire once on the first load of
>   the app, is it true?

Yes it is true. But it should correctly read, *"it only fires once the page is loaded"*

> So if yes it may be difficult to build an else/if statement to detect
>   the right page?

You can build a SPA (Single Page App) or or load `cordova.js` in every single page. On this latter, I have done this. It works.

To be clear, every time you load a webpage, you need to reload ALL libraries. The browser does NOT hold the libraries in memory. This appears to be false assumption you've made.

Comment: Hi understand, thanks but if i add this to my seconde page : `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>       
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        
        function onDeviceReady() {
            alert('device ready');
            window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-6531435-1');
            window.analytics.trackView('Départements numéros');
        }
        </script>` the deviceready don't fire...

Comment: I  should. I can't tell you more without look at your code. You can post to github or similar and I will look at it. Otherwise, I've done this (not with this plugin, but audio) on over 500 pages, with directories 3 deep. As long as I load *cordova.js*, everything is okay.